# Python unresolved reference

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope

If anyone can help me find the error.The variable names (monthly_budgets) are unresolved outside of the function, and when called. I am a new programmer to python so the help and any tips will be appreciated.

```
def monthlbudgetoverview(monthly_expense_budget, monthly_savings_budget, monthly_spending_budget):
    monthly_expense_budget = float(budget_income_five * 4)
    monthly_savings_buget = float(budget_income_seven * 4)
    monthly_spending_budget = float(budget_income_eight * 4)
    return monthly_expense_budget, monthly_savings_budget, monthly_spending_budget

print("Your monthly bill budget is ${}" .format(monthly_expense_budget))
print("Your monthly savings budget is ${}" .format(monthly_savings_buget))
print("Your monthly spending budget is ${}" .format(monthly_spending_budget))

monthlbudgetoverview(monthly_expense_budget, monthly_spending_budget, monthly_spending_budget)
```

Comment: You dont use the return values of `monthlbudgetoverview`... You call it and have a `return` in it but you need to 1) do the call before the prints and 2) assigned to returned value to something.

Comment: Try putting the `print` statements inside the `monthlbudgetoverview` method before the return.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that everything else workins in your code, here is the proper form.

```py
def monthlbudgetoverview(monthly_expense_budget, monthly_savings_budget, monthly_spending_budget):
    monthly_expense_budget = float(budget_income_five * 4)
    monthly_savings_buget = float(budget_income_seven * 4)
    monthly_spending_budget = float(budget_income_eight * 4)
    return monthly_expense_budget, monthly_savings_budget, monthly_spending_budget


monthly_expense_budget, monthly_savings_budget, \
monthly_spending_budget = monthlbudgetoverview(monthly_expense_budget, 
                                               monthly_spending_budget, monthly_spending_budget)

print("Your monthly bill budget is ${}".format(monthly_expense_budget))
print("Your monthly savings budget is ${}".format(monthly_savings_buget))
print("Your monthly spending budget is ${}".format(monthly_spending_budget))
```